# How to install php-5.6 imagick on Debian 10

Tags: php, debian, imagick, debian-buster

Is that possible to install php5.6-imagick on Debian 10? I installed debian 10 and moved my old codebase in it, but site not working with php7 so I have figured out how to install php5.6, but when I'm trying to install php5.6-imagick I've got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5.6-imagick : Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8) but it is not installable
              Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8) but it is not installable
              Recommends: ghostscript but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: ttf-dejavu-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of this: `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1:deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-hirsute.list:1:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list:7:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
/etc/apt/sources.list:8:deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
/etc/apt/sources.list:10:deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:11:deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:14:deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:15:deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
```

Comment: Obligatory screaming: PHP 5.6 hit end of life and stopped getting official security updates over two years ago. Stop using it. Fix your codebase to work with the current version of PHP (8.0.2)

Comment: Please add the output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/`

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ondrej-ubuntu-php-hirsute.list` it is for Ubuntu hirsute:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-hirsute.list
```

Use `buster` codename instead of `stretch` in Sury repository:

```
sudo sed -i 's/stretch/buster/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

Then run :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5.6-imagick
```